# Android. setOnItemSelectedListener.not working

Tags: android, listview

In my android application i define a boolean Arraylist to save which items are checked in my ListView, so i can recover the ListView state.

```
public static ArrayList<Boolean> DataChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

I was trying to change the DataChecked inside this listener, i found on web. This listener alows me to check and uncheck items, i added the last line:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
     CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;
     textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

     //changed
     DataChecked.set(position,textView.isChecked());
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {
}
```

The check and uncheck stuff works fine. But the line i added does nothing, it doesn't update my DataChecked.
Then i implemented this listener, and used both:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parentView, View v,int position, long id) {  

    CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;
    DataChecked.set(position,textView.isChecked());
}
```

Now the function i wanted (change DataChecked arraylist) works FINE! But i don't want two listeners, i want to implement this line on the first listener:

```
DataChecked.set(position,textView.isChecked());
```

So why is this happening? Have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: onItemSelected is coming from which interface?

Comment: He is added to my ListView

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your listview is using that listener.

```
// Use "this" if your Activity is implementing OnItemClickListener
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

or

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
```

or

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
       CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;   
       textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

       //changed
       DataChecked.set(position,textView.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Comment: and another altenative is also to create it as an anonymous inner class,

myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener{
...inherited methods
});

Comment: Hello! I used the code myListView.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener); for both listeners. These lines: CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;   
       textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked()); are working fine.